# How do I use paramertized generic types in an inner class?

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes, parameterized

I am trying to implement an inner class that has a generic parameterized type.

Here is a short version of my code:

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Iterable<T> {
 ...

 private class BinaryNode<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
  ...
 }

 private class TreePreOrderIterator<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Iterator<E> {
  ...
 }

}
```

It does not work. Eclipse/Java is giving me a warning that the type `T` parameter on the inner class is 'hiding' the super class's parameter. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

EDIT: I added the other inner class I'm having problems with: `TreePreOrderIterator`. The generic type `T` will be the same for `AVLTree`, `BinaryNode`, and `TreePreOrderIterator`. The inner classes need to access fields in AVLTree.

EDIT2: Also, the `Iterator` accesses a `BinaryNode<T>`, which is a conflict.

(Note: This is part of bigger project I'm doing for a class. If any other information is needed, please ask.)

Comment: can you edit your question to include how the generic type of BinaryNode gets used?  e.g., is the BinaryNode parameterized by the same type as the AVLTree?

Comment: Just edited. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want `T` in `BinaryNode` to be the same type as the enclosing `T` associated with `AVLTree`, remove the declaration of `T` in `BinaryNode`.

If you want the `T` in `BinaryNode` to be different than the enclosing `T`
        associated with `AVLTree`, but you
        want to be able to access properties
        of the parent `AVLTree`, rename `T` to
        something else.

If you don't need to access
            properties of the enclosing `AVLTree`,
            make `BinaryNode` static.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I changed it to something different cause I need to access properties or fields in AVLTree.

Problem is I'm getting some compile errors now such as, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from AVLTree.TreePreOrderIterator<T> to Iterator<T>" and "Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<? super T>> of the type AVLTree<T>.TreePreOrderIterator<E>."

Any fixes?

Comment: Try `<E extends Comparable<? super E>`.

Comment: I removed the declaration of T (the first option). Now when I write "return new AVLTree.TreePreOrderIterator<T>();" I get the error "The member type AVLTree.TreePreOrderIterator<T> must be qualified with a parameterized type, since it is not static." When I remove "<T>" from the previous code, I get the warning "AVLTree.TreePreOrderIterator is a raw type. References to generic type AVLTree<T>.TreePreOrderIterator<E> should be parameterized."

Answer (score 7):

Just rename `T` to something else so it wouldn't conflict with the outer class T.

The type parameter names are visible in all the class scope, including the inner classes.  So inner classes or instance methods should declare yet another type parameter whose name conflict with the class type parameter.  However, static nested classes and static methods don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove generic type declaration from the BinaryNode class. Since the class is declared private, it can only exist within AVLTree, and therefor you can just use the T declared for AVLTree anywhere inside BinaryNode.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the parameter `T` (as the parameter for the `BinaryNode<T>` class) is the same as that used for `AVLTree<T>` -- the parameter used for `AVLTree` is normally in scope for the definition of the inner class `BinaryNode`, but because you're giving a new parameter the same name, it will be hidden.  You could instead use:

```
private class BinaryNode<U extends Comparable<? super T>> { ... }
```